# How does one delete a CompactLayout via mdapi?

Tags: destructivechanges.xml, mdapi, mdapideploy

I have a descructiveChangesPost.xml file to delete any components no longer required to which I've added a section for CompactLayouts, but it's not doing the delete. Is it not possible to delete these using a destructive xml?

I've tried this

```
<types>
 <name>CompactLayout</name>
 <members>MyCompactLayout</members>
</types>
```

and this

```
<types>
  <name>CompactLayout</name>
  <members>myObject__c-MyCompactLayout</members>
</types>
```

but neither actually deletes it. The CompactLayout is not in use anywhere (I checked).
I can add a new one, update an existing one, but not delete it, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you have to delete a Compact Layout from Classic and in doing so, especially if you have record types, you are asked to choose which compact layout should replace the previous assignment

It is for this reason that the MDAPI doesn't deploy deletions to Compact Layouts as user intervention is required. Note you can't [deploy deletions to record types](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AeeVIAS) either for the same reason (though you can deploy making a record type inactive)

Comment: Ok. I ensured no recordtypes had the layout and it isn't used anywhere, so not being able to delete it via mdapi means I have to manually log in to all orgs (30+) and delete the layouts individually. Bit of a pain. I would've thought that if the layout is not used anywhere, it would be allowed to be deleted. Suppose I can be thankful I don't have 100+ orgs :)

Comment: @Irene - I suppose you could change the label to `xxx (retired)` and deploy using the MDAPI rather than going to all 30+ orgs if you have some sort of devops pipeline